# I found a solution to my own question which has many similar questions. Should I answer them too?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I recently found a solution to my own question, *[sorting a list of 3D points in clockwise order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949485/sorting-a-list-of-3d-points-in-clockwise-order/47956568#47956568)*. (Another user also posted an answer, but the one I found myself appears to be more efficient.) I originally asked the question, because while I found similar questions had been asked before:

- *[Sorting a List of 3d coplanar points to be clockwise or counterclockwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370636/sorting-a-list-of-3d-coplanar-points-to-be-clockwise-or-counterclockwise)*

  - *[Sorting 3D points on the surface of a sphere in clockwise order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307712/sorting-3d-points-on-the-surface-of-a-sphere-in-clockwise-order)*

I believed they were asking for different things, or had no answers at all. Now I realize that my solution is probably what the two earlier askers were looking for, and furthermore that the existing answer on *[Sorting a List of 3d coplanar points to be clockwise or counterclockwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370636/sorting-a-list-of-3d-coplanar-points-to-be-clockwise-or-counterclockwise)* is actually incorrect/incomplete. Should I go back to the two earlier questions and answer them with my solution too?

(Somewhat related, I upvoted the incorrect answer on the earlier question before I realized it was incorrect. Now I cannot retract the vote. How do I proceed?)

Comment: No.  If your solution applies to multiple answers, choose an original Q&A set, and flag the rest as duplicates of that set.